# Wordpress - Pass PHP array from ACF repeater to JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and Advanced Custom Fields to loop through a list of YouTube videos. What I would like to do is create a PHP array in my template of all the video IDs and then pass that array to an external JavaScript file. I think this can be done with `wp_localize_script` but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. Here's what I have so far:

**functions.php**:

```
global $video_ids;
wp_register_script('player', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/player.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
wp_enqueue_script('player');
wp_localize_script('player', 'videos',
  array( 
    'video_ids' => $video_ids
  )
);
```

**single.php**:

```
<?php global $video_ids; $video_ids = array(); ?>
<?php if(have_rows('videos')):
        while (have_rows('videos')) : the_row(); 
            array_push($video_ids, get_sub_field('video_id'));
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

**player.js**:

```
console.log(videos.video_ids);
```

Right now the console log is returning `null` but when I `print_r` the `$video_ids` array on the single.php template it is correctly displaying the array. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the array in PHP but you're trying to access it in javascript.
The following should solve your problem, it encodes the php array as json and echoes it inside a script variable so it can be accessed in javascript. Paste it below your code in single.php like this

```
<?php global $video_ids; $video_ids = array(); ?>
<?php if(have_rows('videos')):
        while (have_rows('videos')) : the_row(); 
            array_push($video_ids, get_sub_field('video_id'));
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    <?php
        $ids = json_encode($video_ids);
        echo "var videos = ". $ids . ";\n";
    ?>
    videos.forEach(video => console.log(video));
</script>
```